# .OBJ Mesh Colors Are Visibly Changing On Rendered Image

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, color

I'm making a game on Unity, and wanted to make a teaser for it. Sounds cool, huh? But here's my issue: I import my .obj model into Blender (the .mtl as well), and set it up. Inside the texture view my model looks correct (just as in the material view), but when I change to the Render view or press F12, my textures look messy:

This (Render view/F12) has the wrong colors.

[image: Wrong colors]

Now, this (Texture/Material view) has the right colors.

[image: Right colors]

**IF YOU CAN'T SEE THE IMAGES'S CONTENTS, RAISE THE BRIGHTNESS FOR THEM, OR OF YOUR MONITOR. THEY ARE NOT PITCH BLACK.**

**AND REMEMBER, THE .MTL IS WORKING FINE WITH THE TEXTURE AND MATERIAL VIEWS, BUT NOT WITH RENDER/F12 VIEW.**

Could one tell me why is this hapenning? Thanks in advance.

---

### ***SYSTEM SPECIFICATIONS:***

**120GB SSD** with **17GB** of free disk space

**4GB RAM**

Intel Core **2 Duo 3.400hz** - *CPU*

NVIDIA GeForce **GTX 1050 Ti** (DirectX **9**, **10**, **11**, **12** supported)- *GPU*

p5wdh deluxe - *Motherboard*

Windows 7

Comment: Your screenshots are all black, we can't see anything. Anyway imported materials are not production ready, manually build new materials using provided textures. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures?s=5|0.6111

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos My screenshots are not all black, its the central part that matters, you know. And you should be able to see clearly the center of the image, as I am. I'm not going to change anything on the images because its meant to be like that. People will only see its content if they bright it up. Anyway, thanks for taking your time.

Comment: No, its not a duplicate question, Duarte, since my materials are working fine on most of Blender, but not with the Blender Rendering mode. Again, thanks.

Comment: need a file to be able to tell what is happening

Comment: In the future it would be best to just upload the file, often the less extra work you impose the more people will be prompted to go out of their way to help. I can hardly see what's in the images (on my end looks like a low res washed out blob) and I'm not going to fiddle with my monitor settings.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out by myself.

I went to the Object's Texture tab, Image Sampling label and disabled Interpolation and it solved my issue.

Again, this is the path:

- **Select the Object**
- **Open Image Sampling label**
- **Set Interpolation to false | uncheck it**

---

Hope this helps future people searching for similar situations.